# Setting up a secure, automated hard drive backup for DNS-321

Tags: backup, hard-drive, netbackup, network-share

My company currently has a d-link DNS-321 hard drive. I want to have it automatically back itself up onto one or more other external hard drives (that need to be purchased). I would like the solution to be relatively straight forward/newbie-proof, because the information on the network drive is extremely important (part of the reason I've been pushing my company so much to back it up). Also, it needs to not be too expensive. Any suggestions (including suggestions on what drives to purchase for the job)?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the manual at ftp://ftp.dlink.com/Multimedia/dns321/Manual/dns321_manual_100.pdf indicates that this product doesn't have any sort of backup to other drive capability (it doesn't even have a USB port).  You could set up a RAID system within it (it has 2 bays), or you get another NAS and use that NAS's capability to backup the DNS-321.  Or you could buy an external hard drive, plug into a computer, and use a computer backup scheduler to back up the d-link onto that.